# Confused about kurtosis and tails compared with normal distribution

Tags: kurtosis

In a book (SAS Essentials: A Guide to Mastering SAS for Research 2009 page 143) it says:

[image: B1]

However, when I look at this picture (not from the book, from the web):

[image: w]

Or also this picture, in case the first one is maybe wrong (also from the web):

[image: p1]

So the leptokurtic (thin) green curve has a Kurtosis which is positive, it is more peaked. Ok, clear to me. But what about the tails? When I look at the right and the left tail, the red mesokurtic curve has heavier tails? I mean there is clearly more area under the curve under the red curve than under the green curve?

Comment: This question is explored at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84158