# Is a Z value of -4.703 statistically signficant?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, skewness, z-score, z-statistic

I was wondering, i have a Z value of -4.7 is this a significant positive skew based on a 1.96 cut off?

And for Z value of Kurtosis of -0.16 is this proving its non significant as its less than the 1.96 Cut off?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! $z=-4.7$ typically gets considered statistically significant. However, that is associated with a test of the mean. Where does skewness come up?

Comment: You should be explicit about what hypothesis you are testing and how kurtosis relates to the distribution under examination. I **think** this is a relevant answer, but the details are so sparse that it's unclear what, exactly, you are asking. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193117/why-is-high-positive-kurtosis-problematic-for-hypothesis-tests