# Does the peak of a Normal Distribution mean anything?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, variance, kurtosis

What does the peak of a Normal distribution show? Let's say if I have a flat peak, does this mean I have a larger variance? What if I have a sharp peak?

For example,

[image]

Does the "blue distribution" have a larger variance?

picture found at "https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/statistics-definitions/kurtosis-leptokurtic-platykurtic/"

Comment: According to the text in your link, only the black distribution is normal. The navy blue distribution is not normal, so it's not really clear what you're meaning to ask. Are you asking about the meaning of peaks of *any* distribution? Or are you only concerned with normal distributions?

Comment: Related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/how-is-the-kurtosis-of-a-distribution-related-to-the-geometry-of-the-density-fun

Comment: The magenta distribution doesn't even have a "peak" or it may have a measurable set comprising its "peak" depending how you define it. Only one distribution is normal. All but two are log-concave. Their only commonality is that they are symmetric. They are all scale distributions, so can be set to having equal variance. It's perhaps more useful to ask which ones have heavier tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your question

> Does the "blue distribution" have a larger variance?

and does not address the broader answer. I recommend [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/how-is-the-kurtosis-of-a-distribution-related-to-the-geometry-of-the-density-fun) as a start point.

The "blue distribution" is the [Wigner semicircle distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution).

In the figure below, $R=2$ which implies that if $X\sim \text{WignerSemicircle}(R)$, then $\text{var}(X) = \frac{R^2}{4}=1$. You can compare that with different [Normal (Gaussian)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) distributions with the same mean but different variances. Note the standard deviation is given in the plot legend.

It appears your "*blue distribution*" has a **larger** variance than the "*black distribution*."
[image: Wigner semicircle distribution compared with Normal (Gaussian) distribution.]

```
% MATLAB R2017a
R = 2;
fh=@(x) 2*(1./(R^2)).*sqrt((R^2) - (x.^2));

X = -2:.01:2; 
XN = -2.5:.01:2.5;

figure, hold on
plot(X,fh(X),'b-','DisplayName','Wigner semicircle, R = 2')
plot(XN,normpdf(XN,0,1),'k-','DisplayName','N(\mu = 0, \sigma = 1)')
plot(XN,normpdf(XN,0,0.5),'k-.','DisplayName','N(0,0.5)')
plot(XN,normpdf(XN,0,0.25),'k--','DisplayName','N(0,0.25)')
legend('show')
```