# Interpretation of $xf_X(x)$, the integrand from the expected value calculation

Tags: interpretation, expected-value, density-function

Seeking the expected value of a continuous random variable we calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\ dx$.
Does the integrand $xf_X(x)$, i.e. the product of $x$ and the corresponding density, have any (interesting) interpretation?

(An analogous question could be posed for the case of a discrete random variable.)

Comment: One interpretation of the above integral is to be the limiting value of an empirical average.

Comment: @Xi'an, thank you. Any interpretations of the integrand, though?

Comment: In the discrete case, $kf_X(k)$ is the limiting value of $k\hat{f_n}(k)$ when $\hat{f_n}(k)$ is the frequency of $k$'s in the $n$-sample.

Comment: You could make plots of *visual means* as analogues of the plot in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/how-is-the-kurtosis-of-a-distribution-related-to-the-geometry-of-the-density-fun/362745#362745   , showing where the contributions to the mean comes from. If $f$ is an income distribution, say, this will show where the purchasing power is. Also search for *partial moments*.

Answer (score 2):

You could see it as the amount of 'leverage' at the point $x$.

In physics, this would be [torque](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) which is $weight \times distance$ or $force \times distance$.

[image: lever]

Comment: Thank you. This is quite brief; additional explanation would be helpful.