# If all moments of a non-negative random variable X are larger than those of Y, is P(X>x) larger than P(Y>x)?

Tags: random-variable, moments, probability-inequalities

$X$ and $Y$ are two non-negative continuous random variables. The moments of $X$ are $\mu_i$ while that of $Y$ are $\nu_i$.

We know that $\mu_1=\nu_1$ and $\mu_i \ge \nu_i$ for $i=2,3,\ldots$

Can one then show that $P(X>x) \ge P( Y>x)$ for $x\ge \mu_1$?

[We do know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260157/moments-of-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-its-cumulative-distribution-function) that
$$ \mu_i=i\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{i-1} P(X>x) dx \ge  i\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{i-1} P(Y>y) dx = \nu_i$$ for all $i$.

It holds for the special case where $\nu_i=0$ for $i=2,3,\ldots$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The conclusion does not follow.**  The family of distributions described at [How is the kurtosis of a distribution related to the geometry of the density function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/84213/919) gives a counterexample.  These are densities $f_{k,s}$ all of which have identical moments.  If we were, then, to shift one of them by some positive amount, all its moments would (strictly) increase.  Here is a plot of their distribution functions $F_{k,s}$ (evaluated numerically):

[image]

Clearly neither dominates the other, even though all the moments of the red distribution exceed those of the black distribution.

---

For those who would like to experiment with this family, here is the `R` code used to create these plots.

```R
f <- function(x, k=0, s=0) {
  ifelse(x <= 0, 0, dnorm(log(x)) * (1 + s * sin(2 * k * pi * log(x))) / x)
}
ff <- Vectorize(function(x, k=0, s=0, ...) {
  integrate(\(y) f(y, k, s), 0, x, ...)$value
})
curve(ff(x), 0, 4, lwd = 2, ylim = 0:1, 
      ylab = "Probability", xlab = expression(italic(x)), cex.lab = 1.25)
curve(ff(x - 0.01, 1, 3/4), add = TRUE, lwd = 2, col = "Red")
```

Comment: I missed your assumption that the first moments are equal.  If we shift $Y$ by $\epsilon$ and scale it by $(1+\epsilon)^{-1},$ further analysis (relying on the values of these lognormal moments) shows all the higher moments of $Y$ are *strictly less* than those of $X.$ For sufficiently small $\epsilon,$ the negative result continues to hold.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for such an instructive counter example!

Answer (score 7):

The higher moments say relatively little about the behaviour of the distribution at small values. The tails have a lot of influence on a distribution.

You can see this in particular with distributions that have infinite higher moments.

For example compare a Frechet distribution with location = 1, scale = 1 and shape = 1.5 (this has finite mean but infinite variance) to an exponential distribution with equal mean.

[image: example with Frechet versus exponential]